# Вопрос по api Method not allowed (fiber(golang) + js)

Tags: javascript, api, golang

Почему - то при отправке post-запроса из скрипта js - получаю ошибку "method not allowed" со следующей конфигурацией заголовков

```
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:5555/api/login
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 405 Method Not Allowed
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:5555
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Allow: GET, HEAD, POST
Content-Length: 18
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date: Mon, 24 Oct 2022 10:55:58 GMT
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers: access-control-allow-origin,content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Connection: keep-alive
Host: 127.0.0.1:5555
Origin: http://127.0.0.1:5500
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:5500/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0
```

Данные запрашиваются  спомощью метода fetch следующим образом:

```
let response = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5555/api/login",{
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type':'application/json',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(auth_data),
            
        })


        response.json()
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(data)
        })
```

серверная часть fiber всегда возвращает JSON формата Status.ok. Даже специально копирнул метод чтобы проверить. Возврат происходит при любых условиях и корректен.

```
app.Post("/api/login", func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
        data := make(map[string]string, 0)
        data["status"] = "ok"
        c.Append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        return c.JSON(data)

    })
    app.Get("/api/login", func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
        data := make(map[string]string, 0)
        data["status"] = "ok"
        c.Append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        return c.JSON(data)

    })
```

В дополнение консоль ругается на cors. Однако добавление заголовка  `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` cо значением * должно было решить проблему, но почему-то не решило.

Метод явно идет OPTIONS, но я понятия не имею откуда он берется...

Может ли такая ошибка быть возвана CORS? С чем может быть связана такая ошибка?

Comment: А что если `method: "Post",` заменить на `method: "POST",` ?

Comment: Не влияет, ошибка та же

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для проверки заголовков CORS браузеры сначала делают [пристрелочный запрос Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request)

У вас, похоже, обработчика `OPTIONS` нет, о чём вам торжественно сообщают в ошибке: `Status Code: 405 Method Not Allowed`. Этот код ошибки означает, что либо не было никакого ответа, либо ответ не включал `POST` в список допустимых методов `Access-Control-Allow-Method`.

Поэтому вам стоит добавить обработчик `app.Options("/api/", ...)`, который возвращает код 204 `No Content` и заголовки в духе "можно всё!"

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT
Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400
```

Заголовок `Access-Control-Max-Age` содержит время в секундах, в течение которого не требуется повторять запросы Options к URL.

Comment: Помогло, спасибо огромное. Не знал про такой нюанс...